# Copy Custom Properties from one object to another

Tags: python

How to copy all object properties to another object with Python?

Could you suggest the simplest way.

[image: Desired process]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom Properties on object level are contained in `Object.keys()`, but there's also a helper property `_RNA_UI` and some API-defined properties such as `cycles_visibility`.

Therefore, it's better to test for `_RNA_UI` and get all actual Custom Properties there:

```
import bpy

ob_sel = bpy.context.selected_editable_objects
ob_act = bpy.context.object

try:
    props = ob_act["_RNA_UI"]
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    for ob in ob_sel:
        if ob == ob_act:
            continue
        for p in props.keys():
            print(p, ob_act[p])
            ob[p] = ob_act[p]
```

Note that properties will added or overwritten, but not removed if the target has some the source does not have. You could change that by deleting all Custom Properties of the target before copying the properties from the source object.

Comment: I got exception with "props = ob_act["_RNA_UI"]"
I got it working only like this http://pastebin.com/Di0r5JrY

Comment: My bad, `try/except` needs to catch `KeyError`, not `AttributeError` to make it work as intended. If you iterate over `Object.keys()`, keep in mind it may copy more properties than you may want.

Comment: the problem is that i always get exception or None with "props = ob_act["_RNA_UI"]". Right now i found the only way to copy all stuff to iterate over Object.keys().

Comment: Please upload a sample .blend, it appears to work just fine on my side.

Comment: Here is the test https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26887202/blender/test_RNAUI.blend   Create an object and run the script - you will get exception.

Comment: Of course there's an exception, because `["_RNA_UI"]` is not created before there's any ID property. You need to catch that exception, see my code above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to the other answer to expand a little bit.

For some reason the other method won't copy the `subtype` of the origin property. This can be interesting if you are working with a `Color` or `Euler` subtypes. Example :

[image]

Also there is now a `is_library_overridable` flag that is not copied over with the script.

[image]

We just need to add a few lines to the origin script :

```
import bpy

ob_sel = bpy.context.selected_editable_objects
ob_act = bpy.context.object


for ob in ob_sel:
    if ob == ob_act:
        continue
    for p in ob_act.keys():
        if p == '_RNA_UI':
            # Make sure the dictionary is initialized (Mainly for empty objects) :
            if p not in ob.keys():
                ob[p] = {}
            for sub_p in ob_act[p].keys():
                # This will copy over the subtype field :
                ob[p][sub_p] = ob_act[p][sub_p].to_dict()
        else:
            # This is a "standard" property (not under '_RNA_UI') - for some reason:
            ob[p] = ob_act[p]
    for p in ob_act.keys():
        if p == '_RNA_UI':
            continue
        # Copy over the overridable flag :
        ob.property_overridable_library_set(f'["{p}"]', ob_act.is_property_overridable_library(f'["{p}"]'))
```

This has been made into a handy add-on by user Scorpion81 (and the help of batFINGER) on this thread (Needs a bit of tweaking though to actually copy over the subtype and overridable flag) : https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-copy-custom-properties/591562/13